# How to convert scala complex object to json for lagom

Tags: json, scala, data-conversion, lagom

I am trying to parse the class object in scala to json for Lagom application

for below class it works fine

```
case class BigQueryRecord(c1:String,c2:String,c3:String,C4:String)

object BigQueryRecord {
  implicit val format:Format[BigQueryRecord]=Json.format
}
```

But it is not working for complex class

```
case class result123(error:Option[String],resultList:Option[List[List[AnyRef]]],resultMap:Option[List[Map[String, AnyRef]]])
object result123 {
  implicit val format:Format[result123]=Json.format
}
```

Can anyone suggest best way to do this..any help appreciated.
Advance thanks.

Comment: I am using lib as import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json, Writes}

Comment: Your resultList should have a specific type to serialize to json. The reason for play json not being able to serialize is AnyRef as your type in resultList as well as resultMap

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar The error seems for option type:                                                          
                                                                                                                 
 Error:(14, 46) No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.Option[scala.collection.immutable.List[scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.Object]]], scala.Option[scala.collection.immutable.List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.Object]]] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)